# Asynchronous validation on uploaded file (React Dropzone + TS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-promise, react-dropzone

I need to validate the duration of the uploaded video using React Dropzone. The problem is every method I have found is async, while the validator function of the library should be synchronous. How can I run async code within the synchronous function?

Getting video Duration function:

```
async function getVideoDuration(videoFile: File | Blob) {
  return new Promise<number>((res, _) => {
    const video = document.createElement("video")
    video.preload = "metadata"
    video.onloadeddata = function () {
      res(video.duration)
    }
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)
  })
}
```

My React Zone validator function:

```
    validator(f) {
      let file: (File) | null
      if (f instanceof DataTransferItem) {
        file = f.getAsFile()
      } else file = f
      if (!file) return { message: "File Expected", code: "IvalidDragObject" }
      console.log(file)

      if (file.size > 5e8) return { message: "File too large (max 500 MB)", code: "FileTooLarge" }

      if (!file) return { message: "File Expected", code: "IvalidDragObject" }
const duration = await getVideoDuration(file) // 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

      if (duration > 15 * 60) {
        return { message: "File Duration should be less than 15 minutes", code: "LargeFileDuration" }
      }

      return null
    },
```

Other workarounds were to use the `getFilesFromEvent` function and pass custom props to the files there, but the events it gives are very different and it is tedious to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I've forked this project [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-async-validation) with the changes necessary to support asynchronous validation. Please note that the `noDragEventsBubbling` parameter is not supported at this point in time. Simply pass in an asynchronous (or synchronous) validation callback function, as seen below, and use as originally intended.

```
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'

function MyDropzone() {
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // Do something with the files
  }, [])
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    validator: async (file) => {
      // do validation here
    }
  })

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ?
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p> :
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```